# How do I add extra room to the bottom of a ScrollViewer in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I am altering a Text Box control to be a code editor in C# WPF. The effect I want is like in Visual Studio when you scroll to the bottom of a code document, it stops scrolling when you reach the end of the text, not when the text reaches the bottom of the control.

I've been trying to do this with a margin or by adding an element of a fixed height. This just puts it below the content host so it cuts short. It doesn't add extra distance to the scroll bar.

This would be easier in a normal scroll viewer but I'm modifying the Text Box's template like this:

```
<TextBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</TextBox.Template>
```

So I basically want to add extra room to the bottom of my content so text doesn't stop at the bottom of the screen. I'm using [CodeBox 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35413/CodeBox-2-An-Extended-and-Improved-Version-of-the) as the basis of the back-end by the way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use `AvalonEdit` instead?